# fatal: [Errno 13] Permission denied when repo init android source 4.1

Tags: android, init, permission-denied, repository

I'm trying to download android source Jellybean 4.1.1_r4. I got the permission denied as the following:

```
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
remote: Counting objects: 1780, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (1780/1780)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (247/247)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (245/245)
remote: Total 1780 (delta 1079), reused 1656 (delta 1046)
Receiving objects: 100% (1780/1780), 463.03 KiB | 240 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1168/1168), done.
From https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
 * [new branch]      maint      -> origin/maint
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      stable     -> origin/stable
 * [new tag]         v1.0       -> v1.0
 * [new tag]         v1.0.1     -> v1.0.1
 * [new tag]         v1.0.2     -> v1.0.2
 * [new tag]         v1.0.3     -> v1.0.3
 * [new tag]         v1.0.4     -> v1.0.4
 * [new tag]         v1.0.5     -> v1.0.5
 * [new tag]         v1.0.6     -> v1.0.6
 * [new tag]         v1.0.7     -> v1.0.7
 * [new tag]         v1.0.8     -> v1.0.8
 * [new tag]         v1.0.9     -> v1.0.9
 * [new tag]         v1.1       -> v1.1
 * [new tag]         v1.10.0    -> v1.10.0
 * [new tag]         v1.10.1    -> v1.10.1
 * [new tag]         v1.10.2    -> v1.10.2
 * [new tag]         v1.10.3    -> v1.10.3
 * [new tag]         v1.10.4    -> v1.10.4
 * [new tag]         v1.2       -> v1.2
 * [new tag]         v1.3       -> v1.3
 * [new tag]         v1.3.1     -> v1.3.1
 * [new tag]         v1.3.2     -> v1.3.2
 * [new tag]         v1.4       -> v1.4
 * [new tag]         v1.4.1     -> v1.4.1
 * [new tag]         v1.4.2     -> v1.4.2
 * [new tag]         v1.4.3     -> v1.4.3
 * [new tag]         v1.4.4     -> v1.4.4
 * [new tag]         v1.5       -> v1.5
 * [new tag]         v1.5.1     -> v1.5.1
 * [new tag]         v1.6       -> v1.6
 * [new tag]         v1.6.1     -> v1.6.1
 * [new tag]         v1.6.10    -> v1.6.10
 * [new tag]         v1.6.10.1  -> v1.6.10.1
 * [new tag]         v1.6.10.2  -> v1.6.10.2
 * [new tag]         v1.6.2     -> v1.6.2
 * [new tag]         v1.6.3     -> v1.6.3
 * [new tag]         v1.6.4     -> v1.6.4
 * [new tag]         v1.6.5     -> v1.6.5
 * [new tag]         v1.6.6     -> v1.6.6
 * [new tag]         v1.6.7     -> v1.6.7
 * [new tag]         v1.6.7.1   -> v1.6.7.1
 * [new tag]         v1.6.7.2   -> v1.6.7.2
 * [new tag]         v1.6.7.3   -> v1.6.7.3
 * [new tag]         v1.6.7.4   -> v1.6.7.4
 * [new tag]         v1.6.7.5   -> v1.6.7.5
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8     -> v1.6.8
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.1   -> v1.6.8.1
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.10  -> v1.6.8.10
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.11  -> v1.6.8.11
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.2   -> v1.6.8.2
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.3   -> v1.6.8.3
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.4   -> v1.6.8.4
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.5   -> v1.6.8.5
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.6   -> v1.6.8.6
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.7   -> v1.6.8.7
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.8   -> v1.6.8.8
 * [new tag]         v1.6.8.9   -> v1.6.8.9
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9     -> v1.6.9
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9.1   -> v1.6.9.1
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9.2   -> v1.6.9.2
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9.3   -> v1.6.9.3
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9.4   -> v1.6.9.4
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9.5   -> v1.6.9.5
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9.6   -> v1.6.9.6
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9.7   -> v1.6.9.7
 * [new tag]         v1.6.9.8   -> v1.6.9.8
 * [new tag]         v1.7       -> v1.7
 * [new tag]         v1.7.1     -> v1.7.1
 * [new tag]         v1.7.2     -> v1.7.2
 * [new tag]         v1.7.3     -> v1.7.3
 * [new tag]         v1.7.3.1   -> v1.7.3.1
 * [new tag]         v1.7.4     -> v1.7.4
 * [new tag]         v1.7.4.1   -> v1.7.4.1
 * [new tag]         v1.7.4.2   -> v1.7.4.2
 * [new tag]         v1.7.4.3   -> v1.7.4.3
 * [new tag]         v1.7.5     -> v1.7.5
 * [new tag]         v1.7.6     -> v1.7.6
 * [new tag]         v1.7.6.1   -> v1.7.6.1
 * [new tag]         v1.7.7     -> v1.7.7
 * [new tag]         v1.7.7.1   -> v1.7.7.1
 * [new tag]         v1.7.7.2   -> v1.7.7.2
 * [new tag]         v1.7.7.3   -> v1.7.7.3
 * [new tag]         v1.7.7.4   -> v1.7.7.4
 * [new tag]         v1.7.7.5   -> v1.7.7.5
 * [new tag]         v1.7.7.6   -> v1.7.7.6
 * [new tag]         v1.7.8     -> v1.7.8
 * [new tag]         v1.7.8.1   -> v1.7.8.1
 * [new tag]         v1.7.8.2   -> v1.7.8.2
 * [new tag]         v1.8.0     -> v1.8.0
 * [new tag]         v1.8.1     -> v1.8.1
 * [new tag]         v1.8.2     -> v1.8.2
 * [new tag]         v1.9.0     -> v1.9.0
 * [new tag]         v1.9.1     -> v1.9.1
 * [new tag]         v1.9.2     -> v1.9.2
 * [new tag]         v1.9.3     -> v1.9.3
 * [new tag]         v1.9.4     -> v1.9.4
 * [new tag]         v1.9.5     -> v1.9.5
 * [new tag]         v1.9.6     -> v1.9.6
fatal: unable to start /media/Stuff/Softwares/Android/jellybean4.1-sources/.repo/repo/main.py
fatal: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: do you have rights to download ?

Comment: /media/Stuff/Softwares  is that external disk you are writing to? Check you have permissions on your repo. as well as the directory.

Comment: Lucifer: before I use Ubuntu 10.04, I can download as normal. I just upgrade my Ubunto to 12.04. I think I have a right a download.

Comment: VendettaDroid: yes, it is an external drive. I have tried this command  to that directory already. sudo chmod a+x -Rv .repo
it still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities are there :-

1. /media/Stuff/Softwares is not of ext2/3/4 formatted (it might be NTFS ,FAT32 ,etc.)
2. /media/Stuff/Softwares is having noexec mount option.

Comment: Siddharth: /media/Stuff/Softwares, it is an NTFS drive. for your second, how to set /media/Stuff/Softwares to have exec mount option as i'm new in Ubuntu command. Hope got your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the the source code from CygWin not from windows Git. To be able to do that  make sure to include curl in the bin directory of Cygwin, and install python within Cygwin packages. Then repeat the steps you have used before inside cygwin terminal.