# fatal: unable to start /*/.repo/repo/main.py fatal: [Errno 13] Permission denied - on nfs mounted disk

Tags: nfs, repository

i am trying to initialize a repo (for yocto development - but it seems to be using the same infrastructure as android).

since I lack space on the OS drive, I nfs mounted another disk (filesystem is ext4 but that probably is irrelevant on the mount-client side).

I try to initialize the repo with the command

```
./repo init -u https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform -b dylan
```

and get the error

```
fatal: unable to start /mnt/lvm/public/.repo/repo/main.py
fatal: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Permissions are fine on the disk. manually I can do file operations without a problem.

Is it impossible to have the repo on an nfs drive (even at the penalty of slower processing)?

Thank you for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied when repo init android source 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650292/fatal-errno-13-permission-denied-when-repo-init-android-source-4-1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the the source code from CygWin not from windows Git. To be able to do that make sure to include curl in the bin directory of Cygwin, and install python within Cygwin packages. Then repeat the steps you have used before inside cygwin terminal.